# Vue-native-script / environment not working

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

When I run

```
tns run ios --bundle
```

Output:

Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.

Searching for devices...

Preparing project...

Installing pods...

Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to find a specification for `Socket.IO-Client-Swift (~> 11.0)`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `9.0` on target `fitness` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Unable to apply changes on device: F5BCC0F3-70B6-40D9-AF43-CBEBE1CEDFB5. Error is: 'pod install' command failed..

Comment: Try running the command `pod repo update`, this will update the pod repo with latest versions, then try tns run again.

Comment: I've tried. It still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do the pod install manually to check where is the problem:

1. Remove your current build: `tns platform remove ios`
2. Build the app source code only: `tns build ios --bundle`
3. Navigate to the project folder `platforms/ios`, run `pod install` to see if there is error. If it's still same error, remove `Podfile.lock` if any, then try `pod repo update`

Comment: Then change the version of that pod to another older/recent version, e.g. `~>10.0`. Otherwise create another Xcode project, add `Socket.IO-Client-Swift (~> 11.0)` + any other Pod to Podfile, do `pod install` to see if it works. If it does not work, then uninstall & reinstall your cocoapod because it seems to be a problem with your pod repo.

Comment: Oh, I just check the git repo of `Socket.IO-Client-Swift`, the current published version is `14.0.0`. Maybe the version `11.0` does not exist.